# Unknown xubuntu screen locker / password

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lightdm, lock-screen

I have a regular ubuntu installation which I then installed xubuntu desktop over. I am occasionally confounded though by an unknown "screen locker" that occasionally appears instead of my normal locker. For example, when my screen saver comes on, and I move the mouse, I am confronted with the following (notice there's a switch user and unlock button):

[image]

On the other hand, occasionally (about 1 in 5 times - the other times I get a 'normal' box), especially after "suspending" (by closing the lid), and waking up the computer, I am confronted with the following:

[image]

note the red border on the password box, and the lack of a 'switch user' button.

When I have the second box I am unable to unlock the computer. No matter what password I use, my user password, etc. it will just not unlock. I have to go to a console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>) and then reboot the computer.

In the past, from the console, I have killed all processes with "screen" in the name, nothing helps.

What is this "broken" locker (so I an identify and remove it)? Which password does it expect (there is no root password, I am the only user on the machine - I have sudo access).

Any thoughts/insights appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue in Xubuntu 15.10. LightDM starts up gnome-screensaver when the device goes into suspend at the lock/login screen.

Run the following to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Comment: This worked for me in Lubuntu 16.04.1.