# Lubuntu rejects password when resuming from automatic suspend

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, suspend, password

## History

- I have Ubuntu. Because of its extraordinarily slow speed (especially after upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04, almost as slow as Windows), I installed `lubuntu-desktop` and now use Lubuntu. The change has greatly speeded my computer.
- I am able to choose whether to boot into Ubuntu or Lubuntu each time I log in.
- After this change, in Lubuntu, the automatic suspend would not work because it asked for the password. I fixed this using the solution to [Authentication required before suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543921/authentication-required-before-suspend).

## Problem

When I resume from automatic suspend, I am greeted with an unusual login screen, which has only three elements:

- The day and time
- The title "Light Display Manager"
- A prompt to enter a password without a user being displayed

When I enter my password, the prompt responds with, "Incorrect password". I have, of course, tried multiple times and typed my password carefully.

I cannot proceed from that screen, and even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> doesn't work. I have to use [REISUB](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/). **EDIT:** I can also sign into a console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and `sudo reboot`.

## Extra notes

If I suspend manually, or if I use Ubuntu, the computer resumes properly with the correct login screen, accepting my password and allowing me to continue. Only the automatic suspend from Lubuntu gives this problem.

## Question

How do I get the computer to resume correctly from automatic suspend when using Lubuntu?

Comment: The `lubuntu-desktop` metapackage installs the `xfce4-power-manager` so maybe the problem is that both `xfce4-power-manager` and `gnome-power-manager` are active. Try to disable suspend from the `gnome-power-manager` and enable it at xfce4-power-manager.

Comment: Do you see the same issue with a pure Lubuntu installation?

Comment: @ThanosApostolou : Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: @DKBose : Sorry, I'm not going to reformat my drive and do a full installation. I don't have that sort of time!

Comment: Hmmm `light-locker` is also installed with `lubuntu-desktop`, so maybe try to disable it or remove it by `sudo apt purge light-locker`.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Thanks for your time. Unfortunately, neither disabling nor uninstalling light-locker helped. That's not really surprising, as Light Locker already knows that Xfce Power Manager is managing the power. I wonder if it would work to disable both Light Locker and Xfce Power Manager, and instead use whatever Ubuntu uses; but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: @PaddyLandau I would completely remove them by `sudo apt purge xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-plugins light-locker light-locker-settings` (I think the only reason that lubuntu uses the xfce4-power-manager instead of gnome's one is because it has a compatible indicator for lxde panel but you shouldnt care if the machine isn't a laptop ). Also check if the gnome-screensaver has a lock screen option and disable it to see if that's the problem. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou — I purged as you suggested (which also removes `lubuntu-desktop`), after which I had no way to suspend. So, I reinstalled the four packages plus `lubuntu-desktop`. After rebooting, it worked! Thank you. Please enter your suggestion as an answer, so that I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/650954/unknown-xubuntu-screen-locker-password, which has an answer (remove `gnome-screensaver`).

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem. After a reboot, the screensaver password screen keeps asking for my password. Entering my password just keeps me going back to the same screensame password screen. Went to TTY and by sheer luck, i saw the out of space notice when I tried to uninstall light-locker. Turns out I had no more free space on my hdd.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick temporary fix:

- Login to a terminal, use `CTRL+ALT+F1` or ...+F2 etc.
- Kill light-locker as admin: `sudo pkill light-locker`

Comment: this only solves the problem temporarily

Comment: It helped me when I needed to be quick. Too bad I pressed switch user which somehow killed my old session.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
sudo apt remove gnome-screensaver
```

There is a conflict between screensavers as LightDM starts up gnome-screensaver when the device goes into suspend at the lock/login screen.

Answer (score -1):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` as administrator.
In the `[UserList]` section, make sure you have

```
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess lightdm
```

(user `lightdm` is often missing)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @ced. I had other issues that forced me to reinstall Lubuntu from scratch. So, I can't check if your solution would have worked :( Incidentally, you used Windows backslash instead of the normal forward slash for the path :D

Comment: Oops. I typed the path manually. Old habits are difficult to quit. Ashamed.

Comment: tried and doesn't work!